# Which control to choose? WebControl or CompositeControl that is the question

Tags: asp.net, controls, web-controls, composite-controls

I'm looking forward to create some customs controls like AutoCompletes, TagClouds and others. To use in my projects as tools without need to worry every time that i need one of them.

i saw in [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71092/what-is-the-difference-between-usercontrol-webcontrol-renderedcontrol-and-compo)

that i have 2 choices.

**- WebControl**

**- CompositeControl**

Those two, they can be reused in other applications.

i read some docs and i'm really in doubt, which should i choose ?

Comment: It largely depends on what kind of control you want to make.

Comment: Agreed. but in example: AutoComplete and TagCloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on how you will implement these controls. If they will be composed of two or more controls (a textbox and a dropdownlist, two textboxes ... etc), then using a Composite Control would be easiest. However, if you are extending the functionality of just one control, or manually outputting the HTML, then use WebControl

Comment: so even when i'm going use one textbox and one image (Like a search that uses one magnifier) for example, i should use composite controls, am i right ?